# clearTimeout() is not working when called via another function

Tags: javascript

When `clearTimeout(fun);`  is added right below `setTimeout` function it works as it should, But I couldn't encounter whats wrong with this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <button onclick="myfunction()">click me</button>
    <script> 
       function myFunction() {
          var fun = setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
       }
       function myfunction(){
          clearTimeout(fun); 
       } 
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

`fun` as a variable is not accessible within the second `myFunction` as it is a variable local to the scope of the first `myFunction`. `fun` needs to be declared globally - or at the parent level of both functions.

```
<script>
  var fun;
  function create() {
    fun = setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
  }
  function cancel(){
    clearTimeout(fun); 
  }
</script>
```

As a side note, functions need to have unique names otherwise the second declaration will overwrite the first.

Answer (score 5):

that's because the identifier `fun` is *only* existent within the containing code block.

The solution is you'll need to declare it outside of the functions, this will enable you to use the identifier `fun` within both functions.

Also, even though your function *identifiers* are distinguished by the first `'f'`, it's a good practice to give them meaningful *identifiers* that can be easily distinguished by the eye.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
<button onclick="start()">Try it</button>
<button onclick="end()">click me</button>
<script> 
   var fun;
   function start() {
      fun = setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
   }
   function end(){
      clearTimeout(fun); 
   } 
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yep, at first glance I thought the two functions have the same name.

Comment: @Leo yup that was pretty hard to spot, but I guess after looking at OPs code a few times.... ^^.